# locale library with Plotly/python dataframe works with jupyter but not with Flask/dash

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jupyter-notebook, locale, plotly-dash

I am using Jupyter notebook working on COVID data wherein I converted date format with my locale language which worked fine. i used the following code and was able to add a column with a locale date.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "ta_TA.utf8")
df_state = res[res['state']=='Tamil Nadu']
df_state_ser = df_state.copy() 
df_state_ser.drop(['district'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df_state_ser.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_state_ser.drop(['active'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df_state_ser.drop(['notes'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df_state_ser.drop(['index'],axis=1,inplace=True)
#df_state_ser.drop(['state'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df_state_ser.sort_values(by='date', ascending = False)
df_state_ser = df_state_ser.groupby(['date']).sum().reset_index()
df_state_ser['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_state_ser['date'])
df_state_ser['tamil'] = df_state_ser['date'].dt.strftime("%d %b %y")
#df_state_ser.rename(columns={df_state_ser.columns[0]:'தேதி'}, inplace=True)
df_state_ser.rename(columns={df_state_ser.columns[1]:'உறுதிச்செய்யப்பட்டவை'}, inplace=True)
df_state_ser.rename(columns={df_state_ser.columns[3]:'குணமடைந்தவர்கள்'}, inplace=True)
df_state_ser.rename(columns={df_state_ser.columns[2]:'இறந்தவர்கள்'}, inplace=True)
df_state_ser.rename(columns={df_state_ser.columns[4]:'தேதி'}, inplace=True)
df_state_ser
```

the attached pic gives the output of data frame. highlighted first date column was converted to locale date format as per the last column

[image]

I am able to use the data frame and get the plotly graph with my locale date format which worked fine too.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
df_long_TN=pd.melt(df_state_ser, id_vars=['தேதி'], value_vars=['உறுதிச்செய்யப்பட்டவை','இறந்தவர்கள்','குணமடைந்தவர்கள்'])
fig = px.scatter( df_long_TN,x='தேதி', y="value", color="variable")
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=None)
fig.update_layout(height=500, width= 605,font=dict(size=10,color="white"),xaxis_title="தேதி",paper_bgcolor= "#2D2D2D",plot_bgcolor="#2D2D2D",
         yaxis=dict(tickformat=".f"),     xaxis=dict(tickangle=270),      legend=dict(x=0,y=1.3,traceorder="normal",font=dict(family="sans-serif",size=12)),
        xaxis_showgrid=False, yaxis_showgrid=False,  legend_title_text= 'மொத்தம்')
fig.show()
```

[image]

made changes to the code as per the below picture and able to get the graph with locale date without any issues.

[image]

if I use the same code above and run in flask application I am not getting the locale date in the graph. I am getting the output as mentioned below.

[image]

need your inputs/pointer to fix the same in flask app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing from locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "ta_TA.utf8") this to 
locale.setlocale(category=locale.LC_ALL,locale="Tamil") fixed the issue with flask